Creating a parent class that can be used in main() to optimize my code
I wanna know how I could make a parent class called "Worlds" and make Celestia Falls and Skypedia children of it. I want this parent class so I can some functions from it like a greeting function or store the trader's inventory in it to better optimize my code. I also wanna make it so when the program runs it picks from a range from however many depending on the world count and from it it loads that world, so every time I run the program it goes through different kinds of worlds.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Player {
    // A class for the player
public:

    map<string, int> inventory;

    int opals = 0, aetherium = 0;
    bool visited_Celestial_Falls = false, visited_skypedia = false;
};

class CelestialFalls {
    // A class for the world of Celestial Falls
public:

    map<string, int> liora_opt, thalor_opt, thalor_inv, eldric_opt, caelus_opt, caelus_inv;

    CelestialFalls() {
        // Initializes the attributes
        liora_opt["Iron"] = 15;
        liora_opt["Gold"] = 25;

        thalor_opt["Axe"] = 10;
        thalor_opt["Pickaxe"] = 10;
        thalor_inv["Axe"] = 1;
        thalor_inv["Pickaxe"] = 1;

        eldric_opt["Apple"] = 5;
        eldric_opt["Dragonfruit"] = 7;

        caelus_opt["Ironsword"] = 35;
        caelus_opt["Diamondsword"] = 50;
        caelus_inv["Ironsword"] = 1;
        caelus_inv["Diamondsword"] = 1;
    }

    void greet_celestial(Player& player) {
        // Greeting to Celestia
        if (!player.visited_Celestial_Falls) {
            cout << "Welcome to the world of Celestia!\nA world hidden in the waterfall of Gonkun Island.\n";
            cout << "Since this is your first time here, here are some Opals to get you started.\n";
            cout << "Opals are the currency we use here in Celestia.\n";
            player.opals += 100;
            cout << "Your current opal count is " << player.opals << " opals.\n";
            player.visited_Celestial_Falls = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Welcome back to Celestia!\n";
        }
    }

    void display_trader_options(bool liora, bool thalor, bool eldric, bool caelus, Player& player) {

        string user_input;

        if (liora) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Liora\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : liora_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " opals\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Iron") {
                if (player.opals >= 15) {
                    player.inventory["Iron"] += 1;
                    player.opals -= 15;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought Iron.\n";
                    cout << "Iron added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Gold") {
                if (player.opals >= 25) {
                    player.inventory["Gold"] += 1;
                    player.opals -= 25;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought Gold.\n";
                    cout << "Gold added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (thalor) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Thalor\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : thalor_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " opals\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Axe") {
                if (player.opals >= 10) {
                    if (thalor_inv["Axe"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Axe"] += 1;
                        thalor_inv["Axe"] -= 1;
                        player.opals -= 10;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought an Axe.\n";
                        cout << "Axe added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Pickaxe") {
                if (player.opals >= 10) {
                    if (thalor_inv["Pickaxe"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Pickaxe"] += 1;
                        thalor_inv["Pickaxe"] -= 1;
                        player.opals -= 10;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought a Pickaxe.\n";
                        cout << "Pickaxe added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (eldric) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Eldric\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : eldric_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " opals\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Apple") {
                if (player.opals >= 5) {
                    player.inventory["Apple"] += 1;
                    player.opals -= 5;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought an Apple.\n";
                    cout << "Apple added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Dragonfruit") {
                if (player.opals >= 7) {
                    player.inventory["Dragonfruit"] += 1;
                    player.opals -= 7;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought a Dragonfruit.\n";
                    cout << "Dragonfruit added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (caelus) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Caelus\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : caelus_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " opals\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Ironsword") {
                if (player.opals >= 35) {
                    if (caelus_inv["Ironsword"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Ironsword"] += 1;
                        caelus_inv["Ironsword"] -= 1;
                        player.opals -= 35;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought an Iron Sword.\n";
                        cout << "Iron Sword added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Diamondsword") {
                if (player.opals >= 50) {
                    if (caelus_inv["Diamondsword"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Diamondsword"] += 1;
                        caelus_inv["Diamondsword"] -= 1;
                        player.opals -= 50;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought a Diamond Sword.\n";
                        cout << "Diamond Sword added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough opals for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    void traders(Player& player) {
        // Displays the trader options and makes them interactable
        char user_input;
        bool run = true;

        while (run) {
            bool liora = false, thalor = false, eldric = false, caelus = false;

            cout << "\nPick one of the following traders to trade with:\n";
            cout << "a. Liora\nb. Thalor\nc. Eldric\nd. Caelus\n\nPress 'o' to display opal count.\nPress 'q' to quit game.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == 'a') {
                liora = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'b') {
                thalor = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'c') {
                eldric = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'd') {
                caelus = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'o') {
                cout << "You have " << player.opals << " opals.\n";
            }
            else if (user_input == 'q') {
                run = false;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select a proper option please try again.\n";
            }

            display_trader_options(liora, thalor, eldric, caelus, player);
        }
    }
};

class Skypedia {
    // A class for the world of Skypedia
public:

    map<string, int> aurora_opt, luna_opt, luna_inv, nimbus_opt, vesper_opt, vesper_inv;

    Skypedia() {
        // Initializes the attributes
        aurora_opt["Iron"] = 15;
        aurora_opt["Gold"] = 25;

        luna_opt["Axe"] = 10;
        luna_opt["Pickaxe"] = 10;
        luna_inv["Axe"] = 1;
        luna_inv["Pickaxe"] = 1;

        nimbus_opt["Apple"] = 5;
        nimbus_opt["Dragonfruit"] = 7;

        vesper_opt["Ironsword"] = 35;
        vesper_opt["Diamondsword"] = 50;
        vesper_inv["Ironsword"] = 1;
        vesper_inv["Diamondsword"] = 1;
    }

    void greet_skypedia(Player& player) {
        // Greeting to Skypedia
        if (!player.visited_skypedia) {
            cout << "Welcome to Skypedia!\nA world in the skies of Gonkun Island.\n";
            cout << "Since this is your first time here, here are some Aetherium to get you started.\n";
            cout << "Aetherium are the currency of Skypedia.\n";
            player.aetherium += 100;
            cout << "Your current aetherium count is " << player.aetherium << " aetherium.\n";
            player.visited_skypedia = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Welcome back to Skypedia!\n";
        }
    }

    void display_trader_options(bool aurora, bool luna, bool nimbus, bool vesper, Player& player) {

        string user_input;

        if (aurora) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Aurora\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : aurora_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " aetherium\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Iron") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 15) {
                    player.inventory["Iron"] += 1;
                    player.aetherium -= 15;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought Iron.\n";
                    cout << "Iron added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Gold") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 25) {
                    player.inventory["Gold"] += 1;
                    player.aetherium -= 25;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought Gold.\n";
                    cout << "Gold added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (luna) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Luna\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : luna_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " aetherium\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Axe") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 10) {
                    if (luna_inv["Axe"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Axe"] += 1;
                        luna_inv["Axe"] -= 1;
                        player.aetherium -= 10;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought an Axe.\n";
                        cout << "Axe added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Pickaxe") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 10) {
                    if (luna_inv["Pickaxe"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Pickaxe"] += 1;
                        luna_inv["Pickaxe"] -= 1;
                        player.aetherium -= 10;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought a Pickaxe.\n";
                        cout << "Pickaxe added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (nimbus) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Nimbus\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : nimbus_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " aetherium\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Apple") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 5) {
                    player.inventory["Apple"] += 1;
                    player.aetherium -= 5;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought an Apple.\n";
                    cout << "Apple added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Dragonfruit") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 7) {
                    player.inventory["Dragonfruit"] += 1;
                    player.aetherium -= 7;
                    cout << "You have succesfully bought a Dragonfruit.\n";
                    cout << "Dragonfruit added to inventory.\n\n";

                    cout << "Iventory:\n";
                    for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                        cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }

        else if (vesper) {
            cout << "\nHello Traveler! I'm Vesper\n";
            cout << "What would you like to buy?\n";

            for (const auto& pair : vesper_opt) {
                cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << " aetherium\n";
            }

            cout << "\nPlease type in what you'd like.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == "Ironsword") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 35) {
                    if (vesper_inv["Ironsword"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Ironsword"] += 1;
                        vesper_inv["Ironsword"] -= 1;
                        player.aetherium -= 35;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought an Iron Sword.\n";
                        cout << "Iron Sword added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else if (user_input == "Diamondsword") {
                if (player.aetherium >= 50) {
                    if (vesper_inv["Diamondsword"] == 0) {
                        cout << "Sorry we're out of this item.\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        player.inventory["Diamondsword"] += 1;
                        vesper_inv["Diamondsword"] -= 1;
                        player.aetherium -= 50;
                        cout << "You have succesfully bought a Diamond Sword.\n";
                        cout << "Diamond Sword added to inventory.\n\n";

                        cout << "Iventory:\n";
                        for (const auto& pair : player.inventory) {
                            cout << pair.first << ": x" << pair.second << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "You don't have enough aetherium for this purchase sorry.\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select an available option please try again.\n";
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    void traders(Player& player) {
        // Displays the trader options and makes them interactable
        char user_input;
        bool run = true;

        while (run) {
            bool aurora = false, luna = false, nimbus = false, vesper = false;

            cout << "\nPick one of the following traders to trade with:\n";
            cout << "a. Aurora\nb. Luna\nc. Nimbus\nd. Vesper\n\nPress 'r' to display aetherium count.\nPress 'q' to quit game.\n";
            cin >> user_input;

            if (user_input == 'a') {
                aurora = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'b') {
                luna = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'c') {
                nimbus = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'd') {
                vesper = true;
            }
            else if (user_input == 'r') {
                cout << "You have " << player.aetherium << " aetherium.\n";
            }
            else if (user_input == 'q') {
                run = false;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You didn't select a proper option please try again.\n";
            }

            display_trader_options(aurora, luna, nimbus, vesper, player);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Player player;
    CelestialFalls celestiafalls;
    Skypedia skypedia;

    skypedia.greet_skypedia(player);
    skypedia.traders(player);

    return 0;
}


I tried asking chatgpt as I am still new to c++ and child classes in general but it gave me some nonsense answer that doesn't work and it kept changing up my code and removing things.

Unrelated: Instead of doing the assignment like liora_opt["Iron"] = 15;, do the initialization in the member initializer list.

"I tried asking chatgpt..." Chatgpt is not a reliable source for solving programming problems. Instead a good c++ book would be much better.

There are a few different patterns implied by the desired behavior on top of the need to understand inheritance, polymorphism, and composition. I also recommend the "good books" and building your foundation first. As it stands, you're going to need more than a parent planet class. You should probably consider a separate trader class, potentially with its own inheritance structure. Any answer would require a full re-write the code you've presented. On top of that, I'd actually say that any answers at this point are opinion-based, and that is off-topic here.

display_trader_options(bool liora, bool thalor, bool eldric, bool caelus, ... - it looks like the different traders should be implementing a trader interface instead of having one big display_trader_options function with ifs to select what trader options to display.

Please simplify your question with a [mre]. A "minimal" compiled code without lots of details in https://godbolt.org helps a lot to express your intent. So far I'll suggest you search for "dependency injection" and design patterns "facade" "mediator"
